# Function calls with pointers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, nsstring

I'm a newbie in Objective C, used to write C. Anyway, I have a class called DataProcessing:

```
DataProcessing.m
...
- (BOOL)MyStringTweaker:(NSString *)strIn : (NSString *)strOut {
    if(some_thing) {
        strOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I_am_tweaked_%@", strIn];
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
...
```

From the AppDelegate (OSX Application)

```
AppDelegate.m
...
NSString *tweaked;
DataProcessing *data_proc = [[DataProcessing alloc] init];
if([data_proc MyStringTweaker:@"tweak_me":tweaked])
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tweaked: %@", tweaked]);
else
    NSLog(@"Tweaking failed...");
...
```

This doesn't work, *tweaked is NIL after the call to MyStringTweaker...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C, like C, is pass-by-value only.  You need to change your method signature to be:

```
- (BOOL)MyStringTweaker:(NSString *)strIn : (NSString **)strOut
```

and use:

```
*strOut = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I_am_tweaked_%@", strIn];
```

to do the assignment.

Then, where you call it, you need to pass the address of the pointer you want to fill in:

```
[data_proc MyStringTweaker:@"tweak_me" :&tweaked]
```

A good explanation is in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

Editorial aside:  Why not label the second argument?  It looks weird to have it naked like that.

Comment: Great, it works! What do you mean by "label the second argument"?

Comment: Something like:  `- (BOOL)MyStringTweaker:(NSString *)strIn output:(NSString **)strOut`.  You have an unlabeled second argument in your example, which is a bit strange.  Look at any of the `NS...` APIs, and you'll see there aren't any without labels.